# Find code for that question am stuck and don't know what to do

Tags: xcode

Find out how many European countries have population over 10 million . Am taking data analyst assessment

1.SELECT COUNT (name) population FROM world.country.                  2. WHERE population  >=10000000 AND continent = 'Europe'                3.ORDER BY population;